# Why we say "Every Fragment-Offset except the last one, must contain a multiple of 8 bytes of data. In IPv4 header

Tags: networking, router, network-protocols, ipv4, fragmentation

I know how the IP version 4 fragmentation works. Also known about the fact that ipv4 "Fragment Offset" field got 13 bits to store the offset bytes and offset can be of 16 bit long in size. So we use 8-byte units (8 byte chunks) to reduce 16 bit length to 13 bit length.

Everything seems fine. But i couldn't get why only in last fragment we don't store the fragment offset in multiples of 8 and why all other fragments  (except last fragment) have 'Fragment Offset' value in multiples of 8.
Then what we actually store in the "Fragment Offset" field of the last fragment???

What is that in "Last" fragment, different?

I tried to find the solution at so many articles over the internet. But every one was talking about the logic behind 8-byte units. No one seemed explaining about the last fragment & it's "Fragment Offset* value...
(Note: i am talking about ipv4 header here, assuming minimum header size as 20 bytes and MTU of 1500 bytes)

Comment: You are confusing some things. Because the Fragment Offset field is three bits smaller than the Total Length field, all Fragment Offset fields will be multiples of eight. It is the data that is is divided into "_portions on a 8 octet (64 bit) boundary_". The actual data length of the last fragment does not need to be a multiple of eight because not all data lengths are multiples of eight.